# Target pattern content no %. stop at line 207 in Qt Linux

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting this error while creating a project in QT. How can i solve it?

This is my line where i am getting error

> ../Error\ in\ \
>   Util.asciify(build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_GCC_64bit-Debug):\
>   TypeError:\ Result\ of\ expression\ 'Util.asciify'\ [undefined]\ is\
>   not\ a\ function./Makefile: ../untitled2/untitled2.pro
>   ../Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf
>   ../Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \

Comment: You could show your code

Comment: you mean the Make file ?

Comment: First, give more detail on how you compile: Are you using QtCreator? Or Cmake, qmake?

Comment: I  just simply install Qt and create a Widget Apliication for check that  Qt is Working or not I just created a simple Apllication nothing else. And I didnt write any code for that I just tray to build that Application and get this error .

Comment: you could show an image of the error message, the format with which you have pasted it does not help to understand it.

Comment: I am using Qt Creator.  @eyllansec

Comment: I dont know which compiler i am using. i am beginner for Qt .How can I check which compiler I am using.

Comment: Where did you download Qt and what linux do you have?

Comment: I download Qt 5.4.1 form this link.    https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/    And I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Comment: I think that the version of Qt you have now is not supported by ubuntu, why not install it from the ubuntu repositories?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qtcreator`

Comment: I just try that but now I am getting error while creating application That is NO VALID KITS FOUND

Comment: first uninstall Qt version 5.4.1

Comment: if you have installed it from the repositories with apt-get then go to the `Tools` menu of QtCreator, select `options`, then go to the `Build & Run` option, and select the `Qt Versions` tab, press `add` and look for the executable `qmake` in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I try all that thing and again i get Error of Target pattern contain %.Stop @eyllanesc

Comment: Note that Qt 5.4 is a quite old version (4 years old), it could be a bug. Why not download 5.10 ?

Comment: I try both version and getting a same type of error.And I am using Qt 5.4 because later on I have to do cross-compile it. @Jean-MichaëlCelerier